# Found this in my wall

Tags: electrical, wiring

I’m extending an outlet when I ran across this random box not sure what it is[image]

Comment: Guessing from the size of it, it is coax cable for tv/cable.  If you can post a picture of a end to confirm.  Should be one thin wire in the centre.

Comment: @crip659 That is definitely **not** big enough to be TV coax. Looks like telephone cable (4 wire, not twisted).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There’s 4 strands of wire coming from the box

Answer (score 2):

That's part of a telephone system.

Comment: Probably. To confirm, check how many strands of wire are inside this cable and how they're colored.

Comment: Yes there’s 4 strands of wire coming out